# Signed long to float and then to signed short

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef signed long     int32_t;
typedef signed short        int16_t;

int main() {
    int32_t var1 = 1200;
    int16_t var2;
    
    var2 = (int16_t)((float)var1/1000.0);
    
    printf("Hello World: %d", var2); // prints 1 should print 1.2

    return 0;
}
```

Typecasting between datatypes in C. As a result, I am trying to get the value of 'var2' as 1.2 in the signed short, but I have got value 1. I have to use the 16bit register and I cannot use 32bit float.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use those ugly typedefs instead of stdint.h?

Comment: As for the problem, you are just using the wrong format specifier for printf...

Comment: You're trying to use `%f` to format an `int` value.  That won't work, they're incompatible.  Your compiler should have warned you.  You need to use `%d` to format an `int`.  And it can't possibly be equal to `1.2`.  That's not an integer.  Are you somehow thinking that you can force an `int16_t` to act like a floating point value?  You can't.

Comment: @Lundin yeah I know that's a mistake, should use %d. right?

Comment: Please note that a `long` may require 64 bits on some platforms, also, please elaborate on *"I am trying to get the value of 'var2' as 1.2 in the signed short"*, what exactly are you trying to print?

Comment: @TomKarzes that's a valuable point. Any recommendation how can I use the Var2 as float and then convert it to 16bit float somehow. Because in my application 16bit float is not supported.

Comment: @Bob__ I am trying to get the value of Var1 as 1.2 instead I get 1 if I run the above code.

Comment: It would seem that the actual answer is to do something like this: `int a = (int) (1200.0f/1000.0f); int b = (int) (10*((1200.0f/1000.0f) - a)); printf("Hello World: %d.%d", a, b);`

Comment: @RanaZeeshan You don't have access to a 16-bit floating point type.  You could use a combination of a 16-bit integer and a power-of-two scale value.  Or you could treat it as a fixed-point value.  But in either case, you'll need to write (or find) code to support your chosen interpretation.

Comment: @Lundin this works on console but how can it be used as int16_t for further intrepretation.

Comment: @RanaZeeshan You cannot store the value 1.2 in an `int16_t`. You'll have to store the integral and fractional parts separately.

Comment: "As I have to stay in the 16bit register..." hmmm... Are you using a CPU with 16 bit registers? Or did you really mean variable instead of register?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374478/will-this-c-16-bit-float-storage-work-on-all-systems-or-are-there-undefined-rou

Answer (score 1):

> `printf("Hello World: %d", var2); // prints 1 should print 1.2`

No it should not.

1. `(float)var1 converts` to `float`.
2. `(float)var1/ 1000.0` - result 1.2
3. `(int16_t)1.2` - converts to integer and the result is `1`

BTW you cant print `1.2` using `%d` format. To 100% correct you should use `%hd` format to print short integer.

Casting does not binary copy only converts between the types

Comment: A couple of wrong/"can't be done" answer and then it gets closed?  Bad form!

Answer (score 1):

var2 is a "signed short" type and it can only contains integer value. If you assign to it a decimal number it truncate the decimal part (0.2) and retains only the integer part (1). I hope I was helpful. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You already have it in a 16-bit int in var1. Your representation is called "scaled integer". Just do the conversion when you need to print the value.

```
printf("%f\n", (float)(var1/1000.0));
```