# Will this C 16 bit float storage work on all systems, or are there undefined routines, etc? Other SNAFUs?

Tags: c, floating-point

In answering a recent Q ([Signed long to float and then to signed short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360119/signed-long-to-float-and-then-to-signed-short), which was closed), I wrote this 16b float storage code.  Are there any major issues with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// simulates a 16bit floating-point #


int main(void){
    union IntAndFloat{
        int   asInt;
        float asFloat;
    } intAndFloat;

    signed int toBeStored = 1250;

    struct Float16bStored{
       signed short significand : 10;
       signed short expBiased   : 5;
       signed short sign        : 1;
    } float16bStored;

    union Float16bStoredAsIntForShifts{
        struct Float16bStored f16;
        short  aShort;
    } float16bStoredAsIntForShifts;

    float toDisplay;

    intAndFloat.asFloat=(toBeStored/1000.0);

    // 12345678901234567890123456789012
    // seeeeeeeeSSSSSSSSSSsssssssssssss 
    //                 seeeeeSSSSSSSSSS 

    float16bStored.sign         =   (intAndFloat.asInt >>31)                      & 0x1;
    float16bStored.expBiased    = (((intAndFloat.asInt >>23) & 0xff) - 127 + 15) & 0x1f;
    float16bStored.significand  =   (intAndFloat.asInt >>13)                    & 0x3ff;

    toDisplay = 1.0f;
    float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.f16 = float16bStored;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("pValue:      %100.100f\n", toDisplay);
        toDisplay += powf(2.0f, (float)((-(10-i)))) * ((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort >>i) & 0x1);
    }
    toDisplay *= powf(2.0f, (float)((((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>10) & 0x1f) - 15));
    toDisplay *= powf(-1.0f, (float)(((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>15) & 0x1));

    printf("Stored as:  0x%x\n", float16bStored);
    printf("Value:      %.1f\n", toDisplay);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you change your integers to *unsigned*. or there might be unexpected sign-extensions. Especially if you use bitwise operations on them.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what this is supposed to accomplish, which you neglected to identify.

Comment: You could add `assert (sizeof float16bStoredAsIntForShifts == sizeof short)`

Comment: `powf()` is a poor choice for raising 2 to an integer power.  For a floating-point result, use one of the [`ldexp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ldexp.3p.html)-family functions instead.

Comment: A sign-bit might be required for the floating-point representation, but it doesn't mean you need it for the integer. Quite the opposite I would say.

Comment: Instead of using unions and bit shifting to decompose floating-point numbers, I would recommend [`frexp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/frexp.3p.html) and [`copysign()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/copysign.3.html).

Comment: Also, you need to watch out for and properly handle NaNs, infinities, and subnormals.  Some of the above suggestions will help, plus you'll want to use the test macros for infinities and NaNs.

Comment: Or actually, `signbit()` is probably better than `copysign()` for the purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are concerned with portability, then overall, this is completely non-portable code.

- You should be using the types from `stdint.h` with fixed size. `int`, `short` etc are non-portable since their sizes vary between systems. `int` and `float` are not guaranteed to have the same size and so on.
- The use of bitfields with member type `short` is not well-defined by the C standard.
- The bit order of bitfields is not specified by the C standard.
- Where/if the sign bit in a signed member of a bitfields appears is not specified by the C standard.
- The endianess of bitfields is not specified by the C standard.
- The compiler may insert padding bytes in structs/unions to sate alignment requirements, so your structs/unions may get unexpected sizes depending on target - they will not necessarily always be `sizeof(short)` bytes large.
- Why are you switching between using constants of type `float` (`1.0f`) and `double` (`1.0`)?
- There is probably no sound reason to use `float` over `double` in the first place. If you can't argue for why you are using `float` instead of `double`, then use `double`.
- `intAndFloat.asInt >>31` is non-portable since right shifts on negative values have implementation-defined behavior.
- `something_with_size_31 >> 31` is also undefined behavior. The right operand of a bit shift may not be of larger or equal size as the left operand (`int` has 31 value bits and 1 sign bit).
- `%x` requires a variable of type `unsigned int`, not a struct or union. This is strictly speaking undefined behavior, so cast the integer member to `unsigned int` before passing it to printf.

There may be other issues that I didn't spot as well.

Comment: +1.  Also, the OP's code assumes IEEE-754 binary32 representation for `float`, which is not guaranteed.  It furthermore assumes a specific endianness / layout of the binary32 relative to the system's `int`.

Comment: And it looks like it can turn some `float` NaNs into infinities.  Which is somewhat moot, because the display code presented doesn't appear to recognize or handle either infinities or NaNs anyway.  And that it will mishandle subnormal `float` values.

Comment: "Since you are concerned with portability"  -- I was not aware of this concern since I onl use 1 system.  Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

> ... issues with this code?

Save time and enable all compiler warnings.  Address those issues first before posting.

Example:

```
warning: conversion from 'double' to 'float' may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
intAndFloat.asFloat = (toBeStored / 1000.0);

warning: conversion from 'int' to 'signed char:1' may change value [-Wconversion]
float16bStored.sign = (intAndFloat.asInt >> 31) & 0x1;

warning: conversion from 'int' to 'signed char:5' may change value [-Wconversion]
float16bStored.expBiased = (((intAndFloat.asInt >> 23) & 0xff) - 127 + 15)

warning: conversion from 'int' to 'short int:10' may change value [-Wconversion]
float16bStored.significand = (intAndFloat.asInt >> 13) & 0x3ff;

warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'struct Float16bStored' [-Wformat=]
printf("Stored as:  0x%x\n", float16bStored);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a strange issue.  131071995 works, but 131071996 does not.  The issue seems to be that the stored float changes values from 0x7CFFFFC to 0x200:

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat 16bFloat-v6.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

// stores a scalled signed int as a "homemade" 16bit float
// (ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374478/will-this-c-16-bit-float-storage-work-on-all-systems-or-are-there-undefined-rou
// and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360119/signed-long-to-float-and-then-to-signed-short)

//max from testing is 131071996 = 0x7CFFFFB

#define SCALE 1000.0f

// SIGNIFICAND + EXPONENT must = 15 (10 + 5 recommended)
#define SIGNIFICAND 10
#define EXPONENT     5

// simulates a 16bit floating-point #


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    union IntAndFloat{
        int   asInt;
        float asFloat;
    } intAndFloat;


    struct Float16bStored{
       signed short significand : SIGNIFICAND;
       signed short expBiased   : EXPONENT;
       signed short sign        : 1;
    } float16bStored;

    union Float16bStoredAsShortForShifts{
        struct Float16bStored f16;
        short  aShort;
    } float16bStoredAsIntForShifts;

    float toDisplay;
    int bias            = pow(2, (EXPONENT - 1)) - 1;
    int biasMask        = pow(2, (EXPONENT)    ) - 1;
    int significandMask = pow(2, (SIGNIFICAND) ) - 1;


    signed int toBeStored = (int)atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("toBeStored = 0x%X\n", toBeStored);

    intAndFloat.asFloat   = (toBeStored/SCALE);

    **printf("1intAndFloat.asFloat = 0x%X\n", intAndFloat.asFloat);**

    assert(SIGNIFICAND + EXPONENT == 15);

    // store it:

    // for ref. (for SIGNIFICAND = 10):
    // 12345678901234567890123456789012
    // seeeEEEEESSSSSSSSSSsssssssssssss 
    //                 sEEEEESSSSSSSSSS 

    **printf("2intAndFloat.asFloat = 0x%X\n", intAndFloat.asFloat);**

    if(intAndFloat.asFloat == 0.0){
        float16bStored.sign         = 0;
        float16bStored.expBiased    = 0;
        float16bStored.significand  = 0;
    }else{
        float16bStored.sign         =   (intAndFloat.asInt >>31)                       & 0x1;
        float16bStored.expBiased    = (((intAndFloat.asInt >>23) & 0xff) - 127 + bias) & biasMask;
        float16bStored.significand  =   (intAndFloat.asInt >>(23 - SIGNIFICAND))       & significandMask;
    }

    printf("float16bStored = 0x%X\n", float16bStored);

    // display it:
    float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.f16 = float16bStored;
    if(float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort == 0){
        toDisplay = 0.0f;
    }else{
        toDisplay = 1.0f;
        float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.f16 = float16bStored;
        printf("Value:      %.1f\n", toDisplay);
        for(int i=0; i<SIGNIFICAND; i++){
            toDisplay += powf(2.0f, (float)((-(SIGNIFICAND-i)))) * ((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort >>i) & 0x1);
            printf("Value:      %.1f\n", toDisplay);
        }
        printf("%x\n", float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort);
        printf("%x\n", (float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND);
        printf("%x\n", ((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND) & biasMask);
        printf("%x\n", (((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND) & biasMask) - bias);
        printf("%x\n", (float)((((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND) & biasMask) - bias));
        printf("%x\n", powf(2.0f, (float)((((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND) & biasMask) - bias)));
        toDisplay *= powf(2.0f, (float)((((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND) & biasMask) - bias));
        printf("Value:      %.1f\n", toDisplay);
        toDisplay *= powf(-1.0f, (float)(((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>bias) & 0x1));
    }

    printf("Stored as:  0x%x\n", float16bStored);
    printf("Value:      %.1f\n", toDisplay);

    return(0);
}
Mac_3.2.57$cc 16bFloat-v6.c
16bFloat-v6.c:51:45: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'float' [-Wformat]
    printf("1intAndFloat.asFloat = 0x%X\n", intAndFloat.asFloat);
                                     ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     %f
16bFloat-v6.c:62:45: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'float' [-Wformat]
    printf("2intAndFloat.asFloat = 0x%X\n", intAndFloat.asFloat);
                                     ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     %f
16bFloat-v6.c:74:39: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'struct Float16bStored' [-Wformat]
    printf("float16bStored = 0x%X\n", float16bStored);
                               ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16bFloat-v6.c:92:24: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'float' [-Wformat]
        printf("%x\n", (float)((((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND) & biasMask) - bias));
                ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                %f
16bFloat-v6.c:93:24: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'float' [-Wformat]
        printf("%x\n", powf(2.0f, (float)((((float16bStoredAsIntForShifts.aShort) >>SIGNIFICAND) & biasMask) - bias)));
                ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                %f
16bFloat-v6.c:99:34: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'struct Float16bStored' [-Wformat]
    printf("Stored as:  0x%x\n", float16bStored);
                          ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6 warnings generated.
Mac_3.2.57$./a.out 131071996
toBeStored = 0x7CFFFFC
**1intAndFloat.asFloat = 0x7CFFFFC
2intAndFloat.asFloat = 0x200**
float16bStored = 0x0
Stored as:  0x0
Value:      0.0
Mac_3.2.57$
```